# How to make GCC compile so that binary uses the new shared object?

Tags: c, gcc, shared-libraries

My program has two C files. One of them is a library that the other one uses. When I change the library and run the executable file, it does not use the new library. The following are the codes.

**main1.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "lib.c"

int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    while (true) {
        printf("%d\n", x);
        sleep(1);
        x = func(x);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

**lib.c**

```
int func(int x)  
{                
    return x + 1;
}
```

I compile the library file using this command.

```
gcc -fPIC -MMD -shared -o libfunc.so -c lib.c
```

And compile the main file using this command.

```
gcc -fPIC -MMD -dynamic -L./ -lfunc main1.o
```

Now I change the library file to the following.

**New lib.c**

```
int func(int x)  
{                
    return x - 1;
}
```

I compile it again using this command.

```
gcc -fPIC -MMD -shared -o libfunc.so -c lib.c
```

Now when I run the binary file, I still see the output of the old library. How could I change my GCC commands, so that the binary loads the library file when it wants to run?

```
$ ./a.out
1
2
^C
$
```

Answer (score 2):

Declare the function instead of including the implementation by changing:

```
#include "lib.c"
```

to:

```
int func(int x);
```

Then you just build the library and binary:

```
gcc -fPIC -shared libfunc.c -o libfunc.so
gcc main1.c -lfunc -o main1
```

and running it will report:

```
0
1
2
...
```

To demonstrate that it uses the new library change libfunc.c to increment by 2 and only rebuild the library as above.  It will now return:

```
0
2
4
...
```

I have `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.` so it picks up the library from the current directory.

Comment: The following is the new code.
`
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int func(int x);

int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    while (true) {
        printf("%d\n", x);
        sleep(1);
        x = func(x);
    }
    return 1;
}
`
I ran the commands you said and this is what I get.
`
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.
$ gcc -fPIC -shared lib.c -o libfunc.so
$ gcc main1.c -lfunc -o main1
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfunc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
$
`

Comment: @EhsanMohandesi It's hard to read without formatting.  The gist seems to be that gcc cannot find the library when you build the binary.  What operating system are you using?  Did you verify that libfunc.so exist in the current directory?